# Quickiest way to check root folders contents sameness?

Tags: filesystems, database

I have some primitive solution but it is too long by runtime:

```
find "/home/user" -type d -printf "%P\n" | sort > "source_1d"
find "/mnt/home/user" -type d -printf "%P\n" | sort > "source_2d"
diff -u "source_1d" "source_2d"                                    # '-_d' means 'directories'

pat="/home/user"; rpt="\/home\/user"
find "$pat" -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 sha256sum | sed -E "s/\s\s$rpt\//  .\//" | > "source_1f"
pat="/mnt/tra/home/user"; rpt="\/mnt\/tra\/home\/user"
find "$pat" -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 sha256sum | sed -E "s/\s\s$rpt\//  .\//" | > "source_2f"
diff -u "source_1f" "source_2f"
```

Can I replace second part of it with disk size usage calculation of second source using in the comparing? Or ext4 does not mean sameness if sizes and belonged folders are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do that is to run `rsync --dry-run`. That will check both trees and output the differences.

```
rsync --dry-run --checksum source destination
```

or you could rely on `rsync`'s quick method (mod-time and size).

```
rsync --dry-run source destination
```

or decide which checksum to use, among the available methods, with `--checksum-choice`. Also, should you need more information on what the differences are, you could add `--itemize`.

Note that doing a full checksum on each file will be necessarily slow, since you have to read them whole.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hardlink -vn`. See `http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/hardlink.1.html`. `hardlink` checks for identical files and links them, but using `-nv` just lists identical files.